# Getting an error message "Failed to connect to the host via ssh" while trying to run ping command on host machines using Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, devops

I am trying to connect to machines and run a ping command on nodes using ansible. I am getting the the below message.

command: `ansible -i inventory all -m ping`

Message:

```
centosinstance | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname centosinstance: Name or service not known\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I have mentioned the private key file and the remote user name in `ansible.cfg` file.

What would be the possible reason ?

Comment: show your inventory file content as well

Comment: There's an error message for you: `Could not resolve hostname centosinstance`.

Comment: @ArbabNazar : Here is the content from the inventory file, "centosinstance
centosinstance1". I have two instances in inventory file ans am getting the same error for both the machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname centosinstance: Name or service not known`

Ansible can't be able to resolve the `centosinstance` hostname. You need to modify your inventory like this:

```
centosinstance ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.10
centosinstance1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.11
```

Please change the ip addresses with the ip addresses of your machines and try again. Hope that help you

Comment: Thank you @Arbab Nazar. Its working now. I have a question here, it is (with out IP address) working fine for play books, but why not for the command  "ansible -i inventory all -m ping" ?

Comment: are you using the same inventory for the playbook?

Comment: Yes, am using the same file for playbooks as well.

Comment: DNS was working fine and now it is not.  How do I fix this without hardcoding the IPs?  The search domain is specified in NetworkManager, I can ping, nslookup, and ssh without fully qualified hostname.  ONLY ansible refuses to work now and it was fine earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parameter has no typo issues as well.

The hostname of my target machine was correct but I had a typo in one of my parameters.

I used ansible_hostname (incorrect) instead of ansible_host (correct).

Answer (score -2):

I was also getting the same error However for me its just typo error like instead of ansible_host i typed ansible_hosts, i.e added an "s" to host.

Comment: Please try to answer directly to the original question and avoid anecdotal responses. Try to understand the original question's context and have fun debugging :)